# Compiling Protobuf to Python giving unexpected results

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf-python

Disclaimer: I am relatively new to Protocol Buffers, and python is not my language of choice. Most of my knowledge of protocol buffers has used them without compiling them, or having an IDE handle it as part of a deployment.

I've been working on updating/fixing an integration with the Steam API. The integration is out of date, and needs a new rpc call, which is in a proto file that has not been compiled to python. I tried the new file and got unexpected results - None of the rpc calls or objects were set up, and all i had was a giant DESCRIPTION blob. To check if this was intended, I tried again, but with a file already in the project, to see if the results were different than the source file. Once again, this appeared to be the case - the newer version has less useful data than the original, and as far as i can tell, is losing information from the .proto file.

I have retrieved the latest .proto files from SteamKit (see https://github.com/steamdatabase/protobufs/tree/ab60110e6ff4766248c73a4dfc1c0beabdad6de5), and followed the instructions from https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/. I am on Windows, and have run both the CMD version of protoc and the one using python via grpcio and grpcio-tools.

Running `protoc -I. --python_out=.\out .\steammessages_base.proto` yields https://pastebin.com/bEMwhCgA  The expected is https://pastebin.com/iGtPqS9V
I have also run `python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I. --python_out=.\out --grpc_python_out=.\grpc_out .\steammessages_base.proto` to see if it was something grpc related. The grpc file is empty, except for the class declaration.

I am using Visual Studio as my IDE, but have Apache Netbeans and WSL Ubuntu as well, should either of those options yield better results.

I have checked other answers on SO, and have not found the solution. That said, i may have missed it not knowing what i am looking for

Edit: Probably goes without saying, but if you are on *Nix, use forward slashes in the protoc commands. Also, the out and grpc_out directories already existed before running the commands.

Edit2: The source .proto file can be found at https://github.com/SteamDatabase/Protobufs/blob/ab60110e6ff4766248c73a4dfc1c0beabdad6de5/steam/steammessages_base.proto

Edit3: In case the links are down, the `DESCRIPTOR=fileDescriptor...` appears identical. The difference is after that. A portion is recorded below as an example

Expected output (original, good file in the project)

```
_CMSGAUTHTICKET = _descriptor.Descriptor(
  name='CMsgAuthTicket',
  full_name='CMsgAuthTicket',
  filename=None,
  file=DESCRIPTOR,
  containing_type=None,
  create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
  fields=[
    #... addition python code here
  ]
)
```

and what i got:

`_CMSGAUTHTICKET._serialized_start=1189
 _CMSGAUTHTICKET._serialized_end=1355`

These aren't the calls i need, but should demonstrate what's going on.

Comment: Your pastebins are not found.  Are they private?

Comment: Don't think so, odd. Give me a second

Comment: Pastebin thought i was a bot. try it now

Comment: [`steammessages_base.proto`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SteamDatabase/Protobufs/ab60110e6ff4766248c73a4dfc1c0beabdad6de5/artifact/steammessages_base.proto) only contains `message` definitions. gRPC extends Protobuf with the addition of `service` and `rpc` types. Absent these types in a proto file, you won't get gRPC stubs generated.

Comment: The pastebins continue to be unavailable. It is preferable to include (a pertinent subset) in the question rather than external references for this situation; there's no assurance that the hyperlinked content will last as long as the question. Please consider editing the question and inserting the relevant subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your issue simply that you need to reproduce the exact generated code? If so, the cause is that the version of `protoc` packaged in the `grpcio-tools` wheel is newer than the one used to generate the code you're comparing against. The most recent breaking change in the generated code was in `grpcio-tools` `1.49`, which has a dependency on protobuf `4.21.3`. Try downgrading to  `grpcio-tools==1.48.2`, which has a dependency on `protobuf==3.12.0` and should generate the expected older format. Make sure to pin to `protobuf==3.12.0` as well for runtime. `grpcio` itself is agnostic to protobuf version, so feel free to pull in the latest version.

Comment: That would be it, thanks. The package actually didn't have a requirements.txt file, and even the 'documentation' of what packages were being used didn't mention which protoc it was using. I'm used to languages that don't like implementing breaking changes so i didn't even think about that.